# Background image shows with scrollbar

Tags: css

I am working on front end and I have attached a background image on the login page. I want to show 100% width and height of the screen to that image but with my codding there is a vertical bar which I want to remove. CSS code of my file is given below

```
.Public_background {
    background-image: url("public_Background.jpg");
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*background-color: aliceblue;*/
    background-position: right top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    /* height:100%; */

    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method I use for this propose

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I took it from [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

[example](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using full screen div you can add this code to your div styling

```
    .Public_background {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle the scroll is because of `gutter` margin -:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.Public_background {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600/300");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="Public_background">
</div>
```